# Different behaviours with events in javascript with and without an event handler

Tags: javascript

I am practising HTML5 and javascript:
I have created a small square that moves with the mousemove of the user.

Though, depending on the way I listen to the event, the square reacts differently.

The first version of the code uses "onMouseMove" and "onClick" in the  tag.
(I tried to put it on fiddle but it did not work..)
-->

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#carre_rouge
{
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    height:40px;
    width:60px;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body onmousemove="souris(event)" onclick="clique(event)">
<div id="carre_rouge">CARRE ROUGE</div>
<div id="carreX"></div>


</body>
</html>  //ip adresses gateway, put numbers

<script>

var nomore =false;

function souris(event){
 if(!nomore){
    document.getElementById("carre_rouge").style.top=event.clientY-10;
    document.getElementById("carre_rouge").style.left=event.clientX;
}
}


function clique(event)
{

    nomore=true;
    document.getElementById("carre_rouge").style.top=event.clientY-10;
    document.getElementById("carre_rouge").style.left=event.clientX;

}



</script>
```

==>THIS ABOVE VERSION works just fine but uses "onmousemove" and onclick in the body tag which is burdening..

Other version using a function addEvent() to control the event.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#carre_rouge
{
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    height:40px;
    width:60px;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="carre_rouge">CARRE ROUGE</div>
<div id="carreX"></div>
<script>


</script>

</body>
</html>  //ip adresses gateway, put numbers

<script>
function addEvent(obj,event,fct)
{
        if(obj.attachEvent)
                obj.attachEvent('on' + event,fct);
        else
                obj.addEventListener(event,fct,true);
}


var nomore =false;

function souris(event){
 if(!nomore){
    document.getElementById("carre_rouge").style.top=event.clientY-10;
    document.getElementById("carre_rouge").style.left=event.clientX;
}
}


function clique(event)
{

    nomore=true;
    document.getElementById("carre_rouge").style.top=event.clientY-10;
    document.getElementById("carre_rouge").style.left=event.clientX;

}

addEvent(document.getElementById("carre_rouge"),"mousemove",souris);
addEvent(document.getElementById("carre_rouge"),"click",clique);


</script>
```

This version can only "push" the square to the right ???

I really don't get why, the code being closely equal.

Can you enlighten me?

Raphael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply because is the first example, your mousemove event is binded on the body while in the second one, it is binded on the element itself.

Now, when you move you mouse in the first example, you'Re always on the body. But in the second example, since your move right on your cursor, when you mouse your cursor to the left, you are not on the div anymore. Your event will not trigger. But when you move on the right, your mouse move on the div since it is place at the right of the cursor.

simply bind event on `document.body` or only `document`. Just like your first example.

```
addEvent(document.body,"mousemove",souris);
addEvent(document.body,"click",clique);
//or
addEvent(document,"mousemove",souris);
addEvent(document,"click",clique);
```